# What's the point of using UnityEditor assembly if you can't build project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title says.

I use a couple of scripts that extend the Unity editor functionality, like SceneAsset class or TagSelector attribute, but now I just realized I can't build my project because of them and now I have to delete all of these and replace them with normal string and fill it myself, which I was avoiding until now.

Do I use these classes only for development? I know I can use #if UNITY_EDITOR #endif so part of the code will only work if built via Unity Editor, but in my case, this seems ugly because I want to declare fields via the inspector. Do I have to declare multiple fields for the same thing and separate the usage or is it possible to make two versions for one field so I don't have to change the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have anything using `UnityEditor` in a build since this namespace is completely stripped of.

You only use it so you can implement editor scripts that simply **only** extend the functionality of the Unity Editor itself ... custom Inspectors/Windows etc.

Make sure you

- Either put these in folders called [`Editor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)! these are excluded from the build automatically
- Or use the [pre-processors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) as you mentioned

Serialized fields should be used for both, editor and build (otherwise you will always get some warning about mismatching serialization layouts). If you need them for the editor, just keep them for the build as well even if they are not really of use there - they don't hurt and nobody will see them anyway.

Comment: Damn, putting the script extending the editor functionality to a folder named Editor completely solved the issue. I had no idea it is so important.

Thank you derHugo, you're saving me again