# Unity Engine not compiling game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just tried to create a game using Unity editor and one of my scripts is as shown:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class KillingBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool dead = false;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y < -1f)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy Body") && !dead)
        {
            GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
            GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
            Die();            
        }
        
    }
    void Die()
    {
        //make player invisible by disabling mesh renderer   
        //stop physics by toggling on IsKinematic in RigidBody part
        //stop moving by disabling playermovement script
        
        dead = true;
        Invoke(nameof(ReloadLevel), 1.3f);
    }
    void ReloadLevel()
    {
        EditorSceneManager.LoadScene(EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

}
```

While building the game, there comes an error

> Assets\Scripts\KillingBehaviour.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My code is working flawlessly in Unity Editor, but I don't know why it says namespace doesn't exist. While coding is Visual Studio, I get all the autocomplete suggestions as a normal namespace gives.

Comment: You're trying to include two different namespaces called `SceneManagement`.  Why?  One of them is producing this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the point of using UnityEditor assembly if you can't build project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298578/whats-the-point-of-using-unityeditor-assembly-if-you-cant-build-project)

Comment: Thanks for your support. I got the solution by removing the unityeditor library and adjusting the editor.scenemanagement to scenemanagement.

Answer (score 1):

Code in the `UnityEditor.SceneManagement` namespace is only available in the editor, because it uses editor features. You cannot use it in a release game build. That means code using it will not compile when building the final game because that game doesn't ship with the editor libraries.

Looking at your code, it seems like you're trying to load a scene at runtime? You should be using `SceneManager`, not `EditorSceneManager`, for that, and remove `using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;` from your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. I tried your solution and it works like a charm.